# How to decompress split zip files on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, unzip

I've got a file (4GB) which is too big to upload on AWS S3 with unstable internet connection, so I split the file into several parts using WinZip.

So, `file.csv` became a series of files:

`- file.z01 
 - file.z02 
 - ... 
 - file.z12`

After uploading it on AWS S3 I need to unzip it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to do it without the help of an EC2 instance.

If you have already uploaded these small zip files, launch a new EC2 instance, download these files from S3 using curl or wget, combine them together and upload to s3 again.

Since you are using Winzip, consider launching a Windows based instance, as it will be tough for you find a linux based equivalent for winzip.